# Как правильно указать и получить id по ссылке на wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Я создаю плагин под себя на движке Вордпресс с отдельным базой данных. Есть админ панель плагина где могу видеть все добавленные мною данные и 3 кнопки со ссылками для добавления новых, редактирование и удаление уже существующих. Для всех я создал отдельное подменю. С добавлением новых я разобрался указываю через menu_page_url(ссылка на подменю 'Добавить');

А теперь главный вопрос не могу разобраться как так же указать ссылку на изменение и удаление по ссылке И С УНИКАЛЬНЫМ ID admin.php?page=eventmaker/em-edit.php&id="id"

[image: Админ панель]
[image: Код Админ панели и редактирования]

P.S. Узнал про $_GET но кажется я что то делаю неправильно можете подправить, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, поместите код в вопрос как текст. 1) индексируется, 2) можно копировать для ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ! Вместо menu_page_url(); использовал [add_query_arg();](https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_query_arg). Создаю свой параметр $_GET(); и даю ему значение и могу выполнить запрос в текущей странице или как в моем случае со ссылкой на другую страницу.

Answer (score 0):

Я предполагаю, что у вас функция `menu_page_url()` создает ссылку, а вы уже ПОТОМ добавляете GET-параметры и они уходят вникуда. Попробуйте создать заранее переменную, сконкатенировать к строке 'eventmaker/em-edit.php' ваш ID и уже потом переменную прокидывать в функцию. Как-то так:

```
$test = 'eventmaker/em-edit.php?id=' . $a->id;
```

Затем вызывайте функцию

```
<a href="<?php menu_page_url($test) ?>"></a>
```

Или, как вариант, докиньте ? для строки параметров. У вас его нет. Может в этом ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Ваш вариант тоже может сработать но я не проверял  так как нашел другое решение.